# implicits in scala Class constructors

Tags: scala, implicit

I dont understand why only one out of the three examples below are working? What makes the other two faulty?

```
class H(implicit a:String, b: Int) {
  //Working
}

class H(a:String, implicit b: Int) {
  //Not-Working
}

class H(implicit a:String, implicit b: Int) {
  //Not-Working
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case `implicit` doesn't refer to `a` but to the entire parameter list. It means "`a` and `b` can be provided implicitly when calling the constructor" (and also makes them available as implicits in the class body). You can't make a single parameter of a class or a method `implicit` in this sense.

The second use of `implicit` is to mark a type/object member. Constructor parameters aren't members, but can be made into members by using `val`/`var`, as in pamu's answer; or, to avoid making it visible, `private[this] val`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class H1(implicit a:String, b: Int) {
  //Working
}
```

Need val or var in below two cases

```
class H2(a:String, implicit val b: Int) {
  //Working
}

class H3(implicit a:String, implicit val b: Int) {
  //Working
}
```

Comment: `class H2(a:String, implicit val b: Int)` will compile but actually won't be an implicit

Comment: @Łukasz It will declare `b` implicit inside the class though. Even more interesting happens with `H3` where _both_ `a` and `b` become implicit internally and externally, and constructor changes to `new H3()("123", 456)`. Dark corners, you never know what lurks there.