# Why implicit parameter not working when combined with non implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

A very simple use case, let's say I have a class `Foo` that is accepting 2 parameters 1 is normal parameter and 1 is implicit.

```
class Foo(val msg: String, implicit val n: Int) {
  def multiplier = msg * n
}

implicit val num: Int = 4
val foo = new Foo("yo")
println(foo.msg)
```

I know it will work if I move the implicit parameter another list i.e. curried `class Foo(val msg: String)(implicit val n: Int)`. But lets say for some reason I don't want to do that.

Can someone explain why the current version of implementation is not working?

Comment: Are you just curious, or do you have some situation where this would be useful for you?

Comment: @suma I recently started working on a project/service (which is old) and it has this same pattern at many places in code which made me curious about it. It seems like `implicit` in this case isn't solving anything or doing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Language specification is written this way. You have to define in a separate parameter list. Language specification is not speaking about implicit parameters at all, only about an implicit parameter list:

[Scala spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html):

> An *implicit parameter list* `(implicit p1,…,pn)` of a method marks the parameters `p1`,…,`pn` as implicit. A method or constructor can have only one implicit parameter list, and it must be the last parameter list given.

It might be possible to check if there is some reason in mailing list archives or other places.

Answer (score 3):

We [cannot mix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287481/5205022) implicit and non-implicit formal parameters within a *single* parameter list because `implicit` modifier [is a property of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688274/5205022), not the parameter. Hence the following method definition is illegal

```
def foo(msg: String, implicit n: Int) = ???      // Error
```

however why then is the following legal

```
class Foo(val msg: String, implicit val n: Int)  // OK
```

Here it appears it is legal to mix implicit and non-implicit parameters within a single parameter clause when declaring a class constructor, however the `implicit` modifier does **not** apply to the formal parameter `n` but instead it is modifying corresponding automatically generated accessor [**member**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39390852/5205022). Because we have declared `n` to be `val` this expands to something like

```
 class Foo {
   ...
   implicit def n(): Int = n;
   def <init>(msg: String, n: Int) = { // note how msg and n are *NOT* implicit
     ...
   }
 }
```

and it is perfectly legal to declare a member to be implicit. On the other hand, if we drop `val` declaration, thus not declaring a member, we see it does not compile

```
class Foo(val msg: String, implicit n: Int) // Error: 'val' expected but identifier found                                   ^
```

similarly to how it is illegal within a method definition. Therefore the reason why the following does not compile

```
implicit val num: Int = 4
new Foo("yo") // error: unspecified value parameter n
```

is because the formal parameter `n` is in fact **not** implicit.

---

As a side note, the following Scala 2 requirement

> A method or constructor can have only one implicit parameter list, and
>   it must be the last parameter list given.

has been altered by Scala 3 [Multiple Given Clauses](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/given-clauses.html#multiple-given-clauses)

> There can be **several** given parameter clauses in a definition and
>   given parameter clauses can be **freely mixed with normal ones**.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> def f(u: Universe)(given ctx: u.Context)(given s: ctx.Symbol, k: ctx.Kind) = ...
> ```

where `given` [corresponds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59865972/5205022) to `implicit`.

Comment: "has been relaxed" If I understand it correctly, `given` still applies to a whole parameter list, it cannot be applied to a single parameter.

Comment: @Suma Yes indeed it still applies to the whole parameter list. I meant relaxed in the sense it doesn't have to be last etc.